# How to mock GetAsync when it is used from a class that extends HttpClient?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I've read a bit about mocking HttpClient, and have found several questions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064031/mocking-httpclient-getasync-by-using-moq-library-in-xunit-test?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53081733/how-to-create-mock-for-httpclient-getasync-method) which all state that when we want to mock HttpClient methods such as GetAsync, we must instead mock SendAsync which is called by all HttpClient methods, like so:

```cs
Mock<HttpMessageHandler> _clientMock = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>(MockBehavior.Strict);

_clientMock.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(someResponse)).Verifiable();

var x = httpClient.GetAsync("someURL");

_clientMock.Protected().Verify(
    "SendAsync",
    Times.Exactly(1),
    ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Get && req.RequestUri == new Uri("someURL")),
    ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

This works fine, and if I run the test exactly like this, it obviously passes.

However, the method I'm testing, which looks like this:

```cs
public async Task<Response<IEnumerable<Instance>>> GetInstancesAsync(string accessToken, bool? enable = null)
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new Client(this._baseUrl, accessToken))
        {
            var url = string.Format("configurations/instances?enable={0}", enable);

            // Creates a request and returns the result
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);
            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Response<IEnumerable<Instance>>>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
    catch { }
    return null;
}
```

As you can see, it uses a Client, which is a class we have created and that extends HttpClient, and I think the problem could be here. When I try to test this method, the solution mentioned above isn't working, and SendAsync is never being called. I don't understand why.

My unit test currently looks like this:

```cs
_messageHandlerMock.Protected().Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>("SendAsync", ItExpr.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
    .Returns(Task.FromResult(responseMessage)).Verifiable();

var result = await _configurationsProxy.GetInstancesAsync(ACCESS_TOKEN, true);

Assert.IsNotNull(result);
_messageHandlerMock.Protected().Verify(
    "SendAsync",
    Times.Exactly(1),
    ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Get && req.RequestUri == new Uri(url)),
    ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>()
);
```

The line `_messageHandlerMock.Protected().Verify(...)` is failing, resulting in

> Moq.MockException :
> Expected invocation on the mock exactly 1 times, but was 0 times", and Assert.IsNotNull(result) also fails, with result being null.

Comment: You aren't using the _messageHandlerMock in your new Client(...) anywhere, so its using its own internal version instead of the mock you created.  Thus, it bypasses your mock check.

Comment: @DanielLorenz so essentially, do I need to give Client a new constructor that receives an HttpMessageHandler, use it in the method to be tested, and then pass _messageHandlerMock to it from the unit test?

Comment: Excactly.  Otherwise, it would be newing up its own inside the Client class.

Comment: @francachu Have you passed the `_clientMock` HttpMessageHandler to the `httpClient` HttpClient at its constructor?

Comment: @francachu there is something that I don't understand, from the method, you call to `client.GetAsync(string url)` but you verify `SendAsync` that get `HttpRequestMessage` as argument. If you replace `ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req => req.Method == HttpMethod.Get && req.RequestUri == new Uri(url))` with `ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>()` the test will pass?

Comment: @DanielLorenz Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @PeterCsala That is indeed the way to go as suggested by Daniel Lorenz. Thank you

Comment: @itaiy Well, the purpose of the test isn't to see if GetAsync is being called, I want to test what the method is returning. For that, I needed a way for GetAsync to not make an actual request to the url. The thing is that HttpClient.GetAsync calls HttpMessageHandler.SendAsync, hence why I'm setting that up to return something back to GetAsync rather than making the request. And my problem originally was that I was not being able to set this up properly as my Client wasn't receiving the HttpMessageHandler mock that I was creating, and so it was never called. Daniel Lorenz above cleared this up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll post the official answer here, then.  Glad it worked!

You aren't using the _messageHandlerMock in your new Client(...) anywhere, so its using its own internal version instead of the mock you created. Thus, it bypasses your mock check.  It ends up newing up its own instance inside the Client class.